# Is this a correct Wifi Network (AirDisplay + IOS + Windows + not really sure if a Correct WIFI Connection)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ios

I'm trying to figure out if the AirDisplay App will work on my iPad. The system requirements for it are:

1. An iPad.
2. A Windows computer.
3. Access to a Wi-Fi network (you’ll need Wi-Fi to get the computer and
   iPad talking)
4. A copy of Air Display for your iPad ($9.99, available in the App
   Store).
5. A copy of the Air Display server software for your PC or Mac (free).

I have the all the requirements (I will buy AirDisplay once someone answered this question) but my problem is I am not sure if I have the correct "WI FI network".

My internet connection is like this:

I am sharing my internet connection with my neighbor through a very long ethernet cable for my desktop. They also provide me WiFi for my iPad and iPhone. The router is located in their house, not mine. Does the Air Display work on this kind of network set up?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a question about the "right WiFi setup" so much as it is a question about connection quality.

How's the WiFi signal strength? Is it wireless B, G, or N? Is it 2.4ghz or 5ghz? All these things will affect the quality of your connection. The lower the quality of the link, the more lag time you'll see on your Air Display. If it's bad enough, the program may not function at all.

Unfortunately, the only way to tell for sure will be to purchase the app. If you have a good WiFi connection, expect Air Display to perform adequately. If the connection is poor and drops constantly, don't expect magic.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back! By saying that, i might encounter alot of problems with Air Display. I have poor wi fi connection. Thanks for making me save $10. :)

i have to try to buy a cable and connect my ipad so it can be my 2nd monitor.